# Mantener tecla pulsada windows.h SendInput() c++

Tags: c++, windows, teclado

Estoy intentando crear un script muy sencillo que mantenga las teclas pulsadas durante x tiempo, simulando la entrada de una persona real. No obstante mediante el uso de sendInput no consigo que la tecla se mantenga pulsada y que en el bloc de notas se imprima 'aaaaaaa' y no 'a' alguien sabe como hacer para que la tecla se mantenga pulsada hasta que se envíe el evento de KEYEVENTF_KEYUP?

gracias, saludos.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// 0x57 w
// 0x20 space
// 0x41 a

int main()
{
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    int x;

    while (1)
    {
        x = rand() % 3;
        switch (x)
        {
        case 0:
            input.ki.wVk = 0x41;
            break;
        case 1:
            input.ki.wVk = 0x20;
            break;
        case 2:
            input.ki.wVk = 0x57;               
        }

        HWND hwnd = FindWindowA("NotePAD", 0);
        HWND hwnd2 = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (hwnd)
            SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
        else
            std::cout << "no se encuentra el programa!\n";

        //boton hacia abajo
        input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
        Sleep((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) *3000);

        //boton hacia arriba
        input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));

        //volvemos a nuestra pantalla y esperamos un tiempo
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd2);
        Sleep((double)rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1) * 10000); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mantener las teclas pulsadas es una característica del controlador de teclado, no de *Windows*, yo diría que lo más factible es utilizar un `timer`.

Por ejemplo:

```
MSG msg;

SetTimer(NULL,
         0,
         300,
         (TIMERPROC)&keypress);
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

La función `keypress` es algo como lo siguiente:

```
void CALLBACK keypress(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
}
```